# How to change the content of a page with javascript based on select input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Let's say I have a webpage like this:

```
    <div style="margin:auto;text-align:center;padding-top:10px;">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p style="text-align:center;">
        <select>
            <option value="blogs">blogs.php</option>
            <option value="portfolio">portfolio.php</option>
            <option value="contact">contact.php</option>
            <option value="home">home.php</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="pagetitle">
    <h5>Option Value (for example blogs)</h5>
</div>
```

As you can see, a user can choose from 4 options in the select menu. I want to know ,is there any way to change the content of this div => `<div class="pagetitle">` with javascript onsubmit ? For example if a user choosed *blogs.php* ,the **h5** tag will change to `<h5>blogs</h5>` & if he choosed *portfolio.php* ,it'll be changed to `<h5>portfolio</h5>` . I really appreciate if you know how to do this ... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind a jquery `.change` event to the `select` element and have it's selected value populated as the text of h5 tag

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function()
    {
        $('h5').text($(this).val());
    }).change(); // this is optional - it basically invokes the change event as soon as the function is registered.
});
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/4/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start by adding a javascript function to handle the event.

```
<script>
function changedSelect(x)
{
    document.getElementById('pageTitleDiv').innerHTML = "<h5>"+x+"</h5>";
}
</script>
```

And then you'll need to trigger the event when the "select" box is changed.

```
<select onchange="changedSelect(this.value)">
```

Finally, I would give the div an "ID" so that it is specifically altered.

```
<div class="pagetitle" id="pageTitleDiv">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla javascript, I added an id to the select element and used javascript to get the value of the select option, then I updated the element on the DOM.

```
<div style="margin:auto;text-align:center;padding-top:10px;">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p style="text-align:center;">
        <select id="myselect">
            <option value="blogs">blogs.php</option>
            <option value="portfolio">portfolio.php</option>
            <option value="contact">contact.php</option>
            <option value="home">home.php</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="pagetitle">
    <h5>Option Value (for example blogs)</h5>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myselect").selectedIndex;
    var _value = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0].innerText = _value
}
</script>
```

Note: This can be achieved in several ways using vanilla JS or libraries, but I think this answers your question.